# How to add a hook to save event for existing DataObject in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I want to make some processing every time when a particular DataObject is saved. If I understand NetBeans IDE API correctly, there is an Savable interface that can be used to implement saving options for custom editors. The problem here is that I do not want to implement my own editor, nor DataObject. I have a MIME type that is edited by a default Gsf editor (the common scripting language api) and has a GsfDataObject (I expect with the DOSavable). I want to keep all that way, just to add a hook, maybe a callback method or something, that would be called every time a save is done upon a given GsfDataObject (and I want a default save action be called, I dont want to override it).

So far I came to this simple solution but it seems ugly (it is more or less inspired by http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqListenForSaveEvents ):

```
// I have a FileObject fobj    
final DataObject dobj = DataObject.find(fobj);
dobj.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(DataObject.PROP_MODIFIED)) {
         if (!((Boolean) evt.getOldValue()) & ((Boolean) evt.getNewValue())) {
            System.out.println(">>>> here it gets modified");
         } else {
            System.out.println(">>>> here the data object gets saved");
         }
      }
   }
});
```

However, this is not called only when the save is done, but also when the file gets modified, but then the modifications are reverted by Ctrl + Z. It only checks whether the data object changes its state from modified to unmodified. Is there a way to hook to a save event only?

P.S.: I tried to call new SJDOSavable(dobj).add(); in the moment when the DataObject gets modified and then to remove it in the other branch. However, the handleSave method does not get called. SJDOSavable class is a simple Savable implemented according to DOSavable from the DataSystems API:

```
private static final class SJDOSavable extends AbstractSavable implements Icon {
   final DataObject obj;

   public SJDOSavable(DataObject obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
   }

   @Override
   public String findDisplayName() {
      return obj.getNodeDelegate().getDisplayName();
   }

   @Override
   protected void handleSave() throws IOException {
      System.out.println(">>>>> but this does not get called"); 
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (other instanceof SJDOSavable) {
         SJDOSavable dos = (SJDOSavable) other;
         return obj.equals(dos.obj);
      }
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return obj.hashCode();
   }

   final void remove() {
      unregister();
   }

   final void add() {
      register();
   }

   @Override
   public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
      icon().paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
   }

   @Override
   public int getIconWidth() {
      return icon().getIconWidth();
   }

   @Override
   public int getIconHeight() {
      return icon().getIconHeight();
   }

   private Icon icon() {
      return ImageUtilities.image2Icon(obj.getNodeDelegate().getIcon(BeanInfo.ICON_COLOR_16x16));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqListenForSaveEvents

Also if you want to listen to global Save events, it seems you can do that now.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=140719

Comment: The solution from my question is inspired by the first link you posted. Still, it can be somehow implemented that way, but I only can listen to all the changes from modified to unmodified state. I just played with the second link, that is interesting since I can now really listen only to save events. However, as you also note, this OnSaveTask API works for global save events according to a MIME type. I got a little bit further, but the problem I am dealing with now is that I want to do a particular action according to a particular DataObject that I retrieve by creating a file.

Comment: So, I create a File, get a DataObject for it, and then I want to associate a save callback to it. So if I create two different files, I get two different DO, and finally I want two different callback objects (not the implementation, just objects). With the OnSaveTask I can decide by associated Document -- each OnSaveTask is created with Context that has a link to the document being saved. So I add my different callback as a property to the document of my dataobject. Then in the OnSaveTask implementation I retrieve it by Document.getProperty(key) and do my processing.

Comment: So in the end the task is done, but to me it still seems a little bit like a workaround. I am gonna give few more tries to the Savable API, because that still looks like the right solution (I am still surprised that the simple attempt to it did not work). Anyway, thanks, it now looks a little better than with the property change listener :)